# How to create a User Role and give permission to only use Web Stories plugin?

Tags: php, wp-admin, users, user-roles

I want to create a new user role "Story Maker" with only the "Google Web Stories" plugin shown in the dashboard for the user to create and publish stories.

I don't want the user to get access to any other thing other than the web stories plugin.

I'm new to PHP and would appreciate it if you could give me the right snippet to add to the functions.php file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm findin the same thing. Once I'll find will let you know.